# Is it best practice to use package.json in an app that is not a module but an end product?

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it normal or hopefully best practice to use package.json in my project even though my project isn't a module/package? I'm currently using package.json for info, version, dep management and I include use 'private: true'

Comment: A 'best practice' seems subjective to me, but I'm pretty sure that's exactly why ``private: true`` was defined in the ``package.json`` format. You can just ``cd`` to your project directory, run ``npm install`` to get all the deps locally and then ``npm pack > project.tar.gz`` to create a nice, fully functional tarball for clients they can just unpack and run without running npm themselves.

Comment: @DavidEllis And if it's a git repo, I'm assuming a lot of people put .git in their .npmignore when doing that? And to deploy would you do a npm install myapp.tar.gz?

Comment: That's basically right. If they're ``npm install``ing the tarball, though, you can skip the initial ``npm install`` step. Since you said in your question that it wasn't a module, I didn't want to assume that it was truly installable (``npm install`` just grabs the deps as defined by the ``package.json`` file, ``npm install myapp.tar.gz`` installs the entire app inside of ``node_modules`` in the ``CWD``)

Comment: @DavidEllis Thank you for your response. I personally don't think my answer is subjective, but what do you recommend I rephrase to make it more objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people are using package.json in applications these days. npm is still a great way to manage your dependencies while developing. As mentioned there are a few ways to ensure that your app doesn't get pushed to the public repository. And you still get the benefits of all the npm utilities.

If by "best practice" you're asking if there is a good reason not to do this, the answer is no. You should go for it.